Contradiction and Godel's incompleteness theorems
If T is a recursively axiomatizable formal system containing peano arithmetic and is able to carry out the proof for the Godel's incompleteness theorems (so according to Wikipedia includes primitive recursive arithmetic) then we have first of all that the theory has a Godel statement G which states that T doesn't prove G and T is able to prove that this statement exists. Second, if T proves G then T proves T proves G but it also follows from the definition of G that T proves T doesn't prove G. That is a contradiction. All this T is able to proof and arriving at a contradiction thus concludes that the assumption T proves G was false that is T now taking all this together proves that T doesn't prove G. This means T is able to prove its own consistency which by Godel's incompleteness theorem means it must be inconsistent.
What am I missing here?


Second, if T proves G then T proves T proves G but it also follows from the definition of G that T proves T doesn't prove G. That is a contradiction.

No it isn't a contradiction. What you can conclude from this is that if $T$ proves $G$, then $T$ is inconsistent. Carrying out this argument in $T$ is indeed possible, and the result is that $T$ proves "if $T$ proves $G$ then $T$ is inconsistent." Or equivalently $T$ proves "if $T$ is consistent then $T$ doesn't prove $G$". We can't conclude that $T$ proves "$T$ doesn't prove $G$" or that $T$ proves "$T$ is consistent".

What about this? If T assumes T proves g then T can derive T proves T proves g which implies T proves not g. Thus it is able to prove a contradiction between the assumption T proves g and and T proves not g. Thus by the principle of contradiction it concludes and proves that the assumption T proves g was false thus that T doesn't prove g thus that it is consistent?

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm No, that's what I'm saying is wrong. "$T$ proves $G$ and $T$ proves not $G$" is not a contradiction. It just means that $T$ proves two contradictory things, i.e. that $T$ is inconsistent. ("$T$ proves $G$ and $T$ does not prove $G$" would be a contradition.)
